# Uniform integrability does not imply integrability of stopped variable

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable

Tried but failed to prove the following assertion: if $ (X_n)_{n \ge 0} $ is a process adapted to a filtration $ ( {\mathcal A}_n )_{n \ge 0} $ such that the family $ \{ X_n : n \ge 0 \} $ is uniformly integrable, then for every finite stopping time $ \tau $ with respect to the filtration, the random variable $ X_\tau $ is integrable.

If the assertion is false, what is a concrete counterexample? By *concrete*, I mean one with the probability space, the filtration, the process and the stopping time explicitly defined.

Comment: uniform-integrability would be nice to use as a tag, but does not seem to exist as yet. Also, read up a few posts in meta in order to decide if math.stackexchange or mathoverflow would be more appropriate forum for this question, but looks like there's no definitive answer.

Comment: There is a lot of cross-over between mathematical statistics questions here and on Maths SE, but mathoverflow is quite distinct because of the focus on research-level questions. Of course it can be difficult to know if a problem is really that hard, or just feels it! As a general rule, I think if you're not pretty sure it's suitable for mathoverflow, it's best to post elsewhere first, and see what other people think.

Comment: Thanks @Silverfish. I find the question's already been asked, and answered actually twice over, in maths SE. The first is an example given by John Dawkins at  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1732198/counterexample-for-uniform-integrability-of-a-stopped-process and the second, by zhoraster at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733735/uniform-integrability-and-stopping-times?rq=1 

Maybe my question could be deleted.

Comment: There might be search engine optimization advantages to keeping your question and marking it as a duplicate - but the way Stack Exchange works, I don't think it's possible to mark a question on this site as a duplicate of a question on another.